# Clarifying usage and definition of 怀疑

Tags: translation, ambiguity, meaning

怀疑 means (1) to doubt, and (2) to suspect. This seems to lead to some confusing translations. For example:

> 我怀疑这张百元钞票是假的

could have two very different translations. If I use "to doubt", then it would translate to

> I doubt this 100 yuan bill is fake

Meaning that you think it's real. On the other hand, if I use suspect, it would translate to

> I suspect this 100 yuan bill is fake

Meaning you think it's most likely fake. These are nearly complete opposite meanings!

I don't believe my understanding of the word is wrong b/c I've heard it used in both contexts (though I may indeed be wrong), but how am I to know when definition is being applied?

Answer (score 3):

First we will deal with the origin (English):

doubt is, in a sense, `questioning something`
suspect is, on the other hands, `distrusting something`

back to your example, you can identify the 2 sentences like this:

> I doubt (this 100 yuan bill is fake)

thus you are questioning the bill's..."fake-ness" which implies you think it's real

> I suspect (this 100 yuan bill) is fake

thus you are distrusting this bill, thinking it's fake.

Now, to the translation:
我怀疑这张百元钞票是假的
is definitly the second explanation - **I suspect this 100 yuan bill is fake**.

The way to express **I doubt this 100 yuan bill is fake** would be:
我对这张百元钞票是假的有怀疑

Hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: What about translating "不过，我总是怀疑你们需不需要我的帮助”. Here is it used as "doubt"?

Comment: Also, does adding  `是否` change the meaning in your example sentence?

Comment: It's the same for "不过，我总是怀疑你们需不需要我的帮助" - I suspect if you will need my help.  the sentence  I doubt if you will need my help will be better like this: " 不过，我总是怀疑你们不需要我的帮助".  I believe there's a mechansim behind it but I am not knowledge enough to give you some references on it.

Comment: you're correct on 否.  I have edited the answer